# Stacked barplot with two categories in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to create a stacked barplot in R to visualize differences in two groups.

My dataset looks like this:

| A | User |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | Male |
| DEF | Female |
| GHI | Female |
| XYZ | Female |
| JKL | Male |
| ABC | Male |
| XYZ | Male |
| XYZ | Female |

I would like the `User` to be on the x-axis, the count or percentage of `A` on the y-axis, and the categories of `A` to be the stacks or the fill or the different groups.

Edit:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=User, fill = A)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "BrBG") + 
  labs(y = "Percent")
```

Is there a way to show the percent labels on the stacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate percentage first, then use those values to add as labels in `geom_text`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  count(User, A) %>%
  group_by(User) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = User, y = pct, fill = A)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(pct * 100), '%')),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "BrBG") + 
  labs(y = "Percent")
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "XYZ", "JKL", "ABC", 
"XYZ", "XYZ"), User = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(User) %>%
  count(A) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = User, y = n, fill = A)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it worked: 
ggplot(data, aes(x=User, fill = A)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "BrBG") +
  labs(y = "Percent")

Is there a way to show the percent labels on the stacks?